# How to navigate with URLConnection?

Tags: java, urlconnection

My application needs some web scraping functionality. I have URL object that downloads all the data. But I need to scrape many pages and I create many URL objects so I open many connections. How to optimize it, so I can have one connection and only navigate to other pages with it?

Cheers

Comment: The connection is closed when the data has been downloaded. This is the HTTP protocol. There is no way around this.

Comment: Most web servers support persistent connections. This speeds up things when downloading the resources (images, css...) for a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you must have a different `URLConnection` for each URL (which makes sense as the underlying network connection must change as well).  I seriously doubt that creating this object is your bottleneck; I suspect it is the network time, but without profile it is hard to know for certain.

For a moderate amount of pages, I would consider a working queue (say using an [`ExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)). For a large number of pages, I might even look into a Java version of [Map/Reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

Edit: For Map/Reduce to be better than a simple worker queue, you need to have multiple computers available to do the scraping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Apache HTTP components](http://hc.apache.org/), it has a lot of features, including a connection manager supporting [concurrent access](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/threading.html)